# How do I analyze a crash dump from a binary in Windows built with Go-Lang Runtime?

Tags: windows, go

How do I analyze a crash dump from a binary in Windows built with Go-Lang Runtime ?

I am trying to analyze crashes from "https://nats.io/download/"

I enabled crash dump creation but I don't see any dumps created.

Is there some other place to see the dump for go-Lang Utils.

https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server/releases/tag/v2.9.18

Comment: What makes you think the NATS server is crashing? Obviously if it is crashing you'll first have to properly configure Windows to create a core dump. Since I don't use Windows I can't help with that. Once you have a core dump you should use [Delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve) to analyze the dump. Have you asked for help on the NATS support forums? You'll probably get better help there than on Stackoverflow.